# How to deprecate a particular type-class instance?

Tags: haskell, deprecated, typeclass

I'm trying to do the following, but constantly running into parse errors while compiling this source-code:

```hs
instance FromRow Job where
  {-# DEPRECATED fromRow "Please do not depend on the FromRow instance of the Job type. It does not handle optional features, such as job-results and job-workflows. Depending upon your scenario, use 'jobRowParserSimple' or 'jobRowParserWithWorkflow' directly." #-}
  fromRow = jobRowParserSimple
```

Is it possible in Haskell to do this? How?

Comment: *"running into parse errors"* – please add the errors to your question! At a glance the code you posted looks ok.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, [as the manual says](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#warning-and-deprecated-pragmas): "You can attach a warning to a function, class, type, or data constructor" with the `DEPRECATED` pragma. No mention of instances. Presumably because its nontrivial to figure out that you're depending on an instance, and particularly not simply a matter of checking whether a certain symbol is used, as it is with all the supported uses of the pragma.

Comment: Though I reckon this should in principle be possible with something similar to the [custom type errors](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_errors.html) mechanism, but GHC only offers this as a fatal error.

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to realize what you seek.

I can only suggest a variant: we can make GHC raise an *error* when the instance is used, unless the user of the instance confirms that they really want to enable the deprecated instance.

This is not an ideal solution, but I could not find anything closer to the goal.

Anyway, here's how it is done. We first define, in the library, some boilerplate class and instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeError
   
class MakeError a

instance
   (TypeError (Text "Please do not depend on the FromRow instance of the Job type. It does not handle optional features, such as job-results and job-workflows. Depending upon your scenario, use 'jobRowParserSimple' or 'jobRowParserWithWorkflow' directly."))
   => MakeError Job
```

Add here further instances as needed, one for each deprecation you need.

Then, still in the library code, we add a class with an overlappable instance, referring to `MakeError` which will generate the error message.

```
class EnableDeprecated a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} MakeError a => EnableDeprecated a
```

Finally, still in the library code, we add the instance we want to deprecate. Here I defined a dummy class, type, and instance.

```
class FromRow a where
   fromRow :: a

data Job

-- Note the deprecation constraint.
instance EnableDeprecated Job => FromRow Job where
  fromRow = undefined
```

Finally, after having completed the *library* code, we consider the *user* code. Here's a dummy test using the deprecated instance.

```
test :: Job
test = fromRow
```

This user code will trigger an error, showing the error message mentioning the deprecation.

If the user wants to disable the deprecation, they can add the following instance:

```
instance EnableDeprecated Job
```

No more errors are now raised.

This solution is not ideal for many reasons. The main issue here is that we rely on overlapping instances, so it is crucial that the last `instance EnableDeprecated Job` is in scope everywhere, otherwise we might getting the deprecation error, even when the instance is present elsewhere. Note that this is an *orphan* instance, which makes the overlapping machinery fragile: the burden is on the programmer to keep this instance on scope everywhere.

Comment: A more practical problem is that it kind of defeats the point of deprecating (as opposed to outright removing) the instance: that a package B using the instance can still be compiled without changes, giving the developer of B time to update it whilst people depending on B from their own package C can still use it with the version of A that deprecates the instance, without having to patch B themselves.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree. I can't see any satisfactory solution, though, with the current GHC.

Comment: Aside, there’s no need to write an empty `where` block—`instance EnableDeprecated Job` is enough